# 500 error on installation since version 2.3

Tags: error-message, admin, installation

I have tried everything to install Craft on my server, and I have not been able to do it. I have done this a few times before without any issues, but since version 2.3 was released, I can't access the admin panel to start the installation.

I have followed all the steps in the [documentation](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/installing), I have created new DB, new domains.... nothing! I get a 500 error every time I want to access the admin area.

What am I missing?

---

```
2014/12/15 19:21:19 [error] [exception.Craft\HttpException.404] exception     'Craft\HttpException' in       /home/content/33/10789233/html/links/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php:737
Stack trace:
#0 /home/content/33/10789233/html/links/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php(176): Craft\WebApp->_processInstallRequest()
#1 /home/content/33/10789233/html/links/craft/app/framework/base/CApplication.php(180): Craft\WebApp->processRequest()
#2 /home/content/33/10789233/html/links/craft/app/index.php(62): CApplication->run()
#3 /home/content/33/10789233/html/links/public/index.php(19):      require_once('/home/content/3...')
#4 {main}
REQUEST_URI=/
---
2014/12/15 19:21:19 [error] [application] 
2014/12/15 19:21:21 [error] [application] Unable to determine if a script name         redirect is in place on the server: Server error response
[status code] 500
[reason phrase] Internal Server Error
[url] http://website.com/testScriptNameRedirect
```

---

Comment: Is is a Craft styled 500 or an Apache styled one? If it's Craft and you check your `craft/storage/runtime/logs` files for `[error]`, you can see what the underlying error message is.

Comment: Apache styled one

Comment: If you have a `craft/storage/runtime/logs/phperrors.log` file, the error might be in there. If not, you'll want to check your Apache error logs.

Comment: Take a look at the error log in the original question

Comment: Try setting http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#omitScriptNameInUrls to true or false (instead of the default `auto`).

Comment: Excellent solution. Thank you. It worked for me. I've spent the best part of a day trying to solve this to no avail.....and it just required that ONE extra line. I can now access the ADMIN section on the live site (and localhost remains unaffected) A nice 'sky-shot' Yuri

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I might be shooting in the sky, but make sure that in your in your .htaccess you have

> RewriteBase /

after

> RewriteEngine On

Comment: This did the trick!

Answer (score 4):

In case it helps someone, my issue was the permissions for the root index.php file...It was 666 (writeable by group) and when I switched that file permissions to 644, the installation was able to move forward.

Comment: This works in certain situations.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problems after updates by a provider.
The solution was add a setting called overridePhpSessionLocation and set it to auto. https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/config-settings.html#general

Answer (score 1):

I had this error, except this solution didn't help. Did some digging and managed to fix using method below:

My setup: CRAFT CMS 3, WINDOWS, MAMP PRO 4.

In your craft folder you can find the error.

craft > storage > logs > web.log

```
cURL error 60 SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Go to https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html and download cacert.pem

Edit MAMP PRO php ini file (file > edit template > php > current version your using

add this to the php.ini file

```
;;;;;;;
;CURL
;;;;;;;
curl.cainfo = "x:PATH TO YOUR FILE\WHERE YOU SAVED IT\cacert.pem"
```

Has to be an absolute file path.

Save, close and reload your server.